# How to handle n number of dropdowns fields with same xpaths

Tags: xpath

I have two drop down fields that are parallel and there is a button as well from where more fields can be added at every row. There is no limit on the fields to be added and have to fetch values from the database with; separated.

Xpaths are the same and I can not use different xpaths:

```
//select[contains(@name,'RoleList$l1$pClassification')]
//select[contains(@name,'RoleList$l1$pName')]
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML DOM structure as well please.

Comment: What is your goal? "Handle" is a pretty generic term

Comment: XPath **aren't** the same. Once You add new node do DOM, it will have it's own XPath. The ones you provided are written wrongly.